# C# - Why does BrowserMob.GetHar() only return 1 entry?

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium-webdriver, browsermob-proxy, har

I am writing some simple C# code to try automatically getting HAR file from Chrome browser. I am using browser-mob-proxy and there is a function: GetHar() which is supposed to return some different entries of URL, request and response time, etc. However, it always return me only 1 entry which is the original URL I am negativing to: www.google.com

I've tried to use dr.Navigate().Refresh() to make sure the page is reloaded so there are some activities on chrome DevTool Network section.

```
        server.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Client client = server.CreateProxy();
        client.NewHar("google");
        var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        var seleniumProxy = new Proxy { HttpProxy = client.SeleniumProxy };
        chromeOptions.Proxy = seleniumProxy;
        var dr = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);       

        dr.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
        dr.FindElementByClassName("gb_e").Click();

        Thread.Sleep(3500);
        dr.Navigate().Refresh();


        // Get the performance stats
        HarResult harData = client.GetHar();
        Log log = harData.Log;
        Entry[] entries = log.Entries;

        foreach (var e in entries)
        {
            Request request = e.Request;
            Response response = e.Response;
            var url = request.Url;
            var time = e.Time;
            var status = response.Status;
            var testStr = "Url: " + url + " - Time: " + time + " Response: " + status;
        }
```

I expected GetHar() function will return more entries instead of only 1.

Comment: Seen the example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/devtools.network/getHAR)?

Comment: How did you create the server? I have been looking for the C# version of browsermob but could nt find anything. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why, but the issue has been resolved by adding SSL proxy:

```
var seleniumProxy = new Proxy { HttpProxy = client.SeleniumProxy , SslProxy = client.SeleniumProxy };
```

Comment: What do you use for using for Server and Client?  I can't get them to be recognized and the one way I can with a Microsoft library installs a boat load of stuff and doesn't support the Stop() method so probably the wrong library to link